# Adding a new item to a dojo.data.itemFileWriteStore without an identifier

Tags: dojo

I have a `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` linked to a `dojo.data.itemFileWriteStore` and I want to add a new item. The identifier for the store is the auto-incremented primary key from the table.

How can I add a new item without providing an identifier, with the intention that the MySQL DB will then create an identifier once it is inserted?

Comment: I've found a way around this. I add to the table directly and then refresh the store. In order to refresh the store I've set the properties urlPreventCache and clearOnClose, then after the insert I call close() on the store.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my comment as an answer as this has been open for quite some time and I've found a workaround:

I've found a way around this. I add to the table directly and then refresh the store. In order to refresh the store I've set the properties urlPreventCache and clearOnClose, then after the insert I call close() on the store.